# How do I implement custom error pages in NuxtJS 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to get my NuxtJS 3 app to show custom error pages. The app is universal with SSR. The NuxtJS 2 docs say to add a `layouts/error.vue` file and it should get picked up. However, while using NuxtJS 3, my custom page is never shown - either through a hard reload or navigating to a broken link with a `<NuxtLink>` via the router.

Have custom error pages in NuxtJS 3 changed? There doesn't seem to be any documentation on them in the docs https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/layouts

Comment: Maybe give a look to this one: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/559

Comment: Thank you @kissu it seems custom error pages are still a work in progress. NuxtJS 3 is still in beta at the time of this writing.

Comment: Yep exactly. Some stuff still needs to be figured out by the maintainer/community!

Answer (score 3):

https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/error-handling/#example

> You can customize this error page by adding ~/error.vue in the source
> directory of your application, alongside app.vue. This page has a
> single prop - error which contains an error for you to handle.

*./error.vue (alongside app.vue)*

```
<template>
  <button @click="handleError">Clear errors</button>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  error: Object
})

const handleError = () => clearError({ redirect: '/' })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the error page in the root and not in the layouts folder, it works!